# Jetty 9.2.3 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, http, servlets, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Here is our Jetty 9.2.3 server configuration and followed by the “java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException” stack trace I end up getting on our server.

Scenario: In our dev environment, I am constantly sending 25 concurrent requests at a time to the Jetty server and I immediately get “java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException” exception for some of the requests, not all.

Exception: Full stack trace is pasted below. Exception occurs after reading the partial json request in the http request body and then rest of the json request doesn’t come through the http request’s input stream thereby causing IO block thats kicks in the idle time out milliseconds and times out.

Where am I going wrong thats causing time out exception? Please advice. Thank you.

Server Configuration:

```
//new ExecutorThreadPool(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
Server server = new Server(new ExecutorThreadPool(25, 50, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
configuration.setRequestHeaderSize(8192);    
LowResourceMonitor lowResourceMonitor = new LowResourceMonitor(server);
lowResourceMonitor.setLowResourcesIdleTimeout(150);
lowResourceMonitor.setMaxConnections(700);
server.addBean(lowResourceMonitor);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new         HttpConnectionFactory(configuration));
connector.setHost(host);
connector.setPort(port);
connector.setIdleTimeout(300);
connector.setAcceptQueueSize(256);
connector.setReuseAddress(true);
connector.accept(1);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
```

Exception:

```
2014-11-02 20:17:36,481 [ERROR] [pool-39-thread-13] c.t.gth.e.DE - Error trying to get:          java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 200/200 ms
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 200/200 ms
    at         org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:234) ~[jetty-    util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP.blockForContent(HttpInputOverHTTP.java:66) ~[jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$1.waitForContent(HttpInput.java:456) ~[jetty-    server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:121) ~[jetty-server-    9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2001) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1980) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1957) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1907) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at com.xyz.gth.adapter.MOP.convertStreamToString(MOP.java:729) ~[bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at com.xyz.gth.adapter.MOP.handleRequest(MOP.java:129) ~[bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at com.xyz.gth.adapter.MoPubFilterAdapter.handleRequest(MoPubFilterAdapter.java:65) ~[bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at com.xyz.gth.e.ED.getTBR(ED.java:1600) [bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at com.xyz.gth.e.ED.process(ED.java:613) [bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at com.xyz.gth.eHandler.handle(eHandler.java:122) [bdd-1.19.18.3.3.1.jar:1.19.18.3.3.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 200/200 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:156) ~[jetty-io-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50) ~[jetty-io-9.2.3.v20140905.jar:9.2.3.v20140905]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```